TLS Termination in K8S Gateway API (azure implemetation) Resource?
we are in the process of setting up a Azure Application Gateway for containers, which is an implementation of the k8s Gateway API.
I have been able to set up a working POC with TLS termination in the Gateway and multi-site hosting.
However, the problem I have is that I want to deploy these resources using our custom helm chart used for app deployments.
The way I have been able to set it up so far, is to add multiple TLS certificates in the gateway resource:
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.networking.azure.io/alb-name: alb-test-spoke-2
    alb.networking.azure.io/alb-namespace:system
  name: alb-gw-tls
  namespace:system
spec:
  gatewayClassName: azure-alb-external
  listeners:
  - allowedRoutes:
      namespaces:
        from: All
    hostname: first-api.dev
    name: https-listener-first-api
    port: 443
    protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      certificateRefs:
      - kind: Secret
        name: first-api-tls-certificate
      mode: Terminate
  - allowedRoutes:
      namespaces:
        from: All
    hostname: second-api.dev
    name: https-listener-second-api
    port: 443
    protocol: HTTPS
    tls:
      certificateRefs:
      - kind: Secret
        name: second-api-tls-certificate
      mode: Terminate

This works, but it is not afaik feasible to make this work with a helm chart, as this approach requires me to add a new route/tls cert ref to the gateway for every new app manually, which I dont want to do.
I could create a new gateway for every application, but for some reason Azure limits the number of gateways(frontends) connected to a Azure Application Gateway for containers to 5, which makes this approach very akward.
I tried looking into terminating the TLS in the HttpRoute Resouce, but that does not seem like a supported feature.
Does anyone else have a suggestion to how I can create these resources as standalone resources(files), making it easy to deploy using our helm-chart?

Can you add {{- range .Values.listeners }} to loop over a list of listener entries, which allows for adding multiple hostnames and TLS certificates without modifying the main YAML structure directly. checkout https://mustafaak4096.medium.com/loops-in-helm-charts-259e1b9e8422

I have thought of that, but my idea is to generate the Gateway resource upon cluster creation, using chart #1, and then as I add apps to the cluster i will be doing that using chart #2. The problem is that I dont want to update chart #1 for every new app in the cluster. As of now I am looking at a wildcard cert solution, that will enable the pattern I want, but it is not an ideal solution the way I see it.

So do you have a wildcard certificate? If yes then that can be referenced by the Gateway for TLS termination. Then for each application, you define a new HTTPRoute resource which should allow you to add apps dynamically without modifying the GW. Then create 2 helm charts, one that deploys the GW and wildcard cert and another chart used for each app to deploy these unique HTTPRoute and dynamically adding routes. Sounds good?

Yes, that is my approach as of now, but I was hoping to avoid using wildcard certs...
Another approach is to check if it is possible to increase the limit for number of frontends connected to a ALB, if yes, I could create one GateWay Object per application, which would also solve my problem..

Increasing the number of frontends / gateways connected to an app gateway for containers is currently limited to a maximum of five by Azure, and unfortunately, this limit cannot be directly increased at this time. -   Application Gateway for Containers limits so you are left with 2 options, either you make 2 helm charts which you don't want and other is your wildcard option

As discussed, Azure Application Gateway for Containers has a limit of five frontends per gateway, which currently cannot be increased. To work around this limitation, you can use a wildcard certificate, allowing a single Gateway resource to handle TLS termination for multiple subdomains. With this setup, you only need to manage HTTPRoute resources for each new app, eliminating frequent updates to the main Gateway configuration.
Install the Gateway API CRDs on your cluster
kubectl apply -k "github.com/kubernetes-sigs/gateway-api/config/crd/experimental?ref=v0.5.0"

If you have a wildcard certificate, create a secret for it, or if you’re using individual certificates for each hostname, create secrets for each certificate.


Update your Gateway yaml with TLS termination using the wildcard or individual certificates.
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.networking.azure.io/alb-name: alb-test-spoke-2
    alb.networking.azure.io/alb-namespace: system
  name: alb-gw-tls
  namespace: system
spec:
  gatewayClassName: azure-alb-external
  listeners:
    - name: https-listener-first-api
      port: 443
      protocol: HTTPS
      hostname: "first-api.dev"
      tls:
        mode: Terminate
        certificateRefs:
          - kind: Secret
            name: first-api-tls-certificate
            namespace: system
      allowedRoutes:
        namespaces:
          from: All
    - name: https-listener-second-api
      port: 443
      protocol: HTTPS
      hostname: "second-api.dev"
      tls:
        mode: Terminate
        certificateRefs:
          - kind: Secret
            name: second-api-tls-certificate
            namespace: system
      allowedRoutes:
        namespaces:
          from: All


Create a Helm Chart for the Gateway to simplify adding multiple listeners dynamically.

Edit below values
values.yaml
listeners:
  - hostname: "first-api.dev"
    tlsSecretName: "first-api-tls-certificate"
  - hostname: "second-api.dev"
    tlsSecretName: "second-api-tls-certificate"

templates/gateway.yaml
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  annotations:
    alb.networking.azure.io/alb-name: alb-test-spoke-2
    alb.networking.azure.io/alb-namespace: system
  name: alb-gw-tls
  namespace: system
spec:
  gatewayClassName: azure-alb-external
  listeners:
    {{- range .Values.listeners }}
    - name: https-listener-{{ .hostname | replace "." "-" }}
      port: 443
      protocol: HTTPS
      hostname: {{ .hostname }}
      tls:
        mode: Terminate
        certificateRefs:
          - name: {{ .tlsSecretName }}
            kind: Secret
            namespace: system
      allowedRoutes:
        namespaces:
          from: All
    {{- end }}

Deploy the Gateway Chart
 helm install alb-gateway ./gateway-chart -n system

This command will create the Gateway with listeners for first-api.dev and second-api.dev. If you need to add additional listeners in the future, simply update values.yaml
For each application, create a separate HTTPRoute resource that references the Gateway. This setup allows you to route traffic to new applications without modifying the Gateway configuration.
apiVersion: gateway.networking.k8s.io/v1alpha2
kind: HTTPRoute
metadata:
  name: first-api-route
  namespace: app-namespace
spec:
  parentRefs:
    - name: alb-gw-tls
      namespace: system
  hostnames:
    - "first-api.dev"
  rules:
    - matches:
        - path:
            type: Prefix
            value: /
      backendRefs:
        - name: first-api-service
          port: 80


